# DTV Player and another program activity

Tags: android, android-tv

we have a service program working on android when timer is elapsed our service showing one activity. this activity is transparent has 3 button thats it, so when dtv or other video program is active our activity coming black and DTV or video is pausing our question is how can we show this activity DTV or video when playing without pausing or black screen?

**EDIT**

here how i call activity

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(AdvActivity));
 intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
 intent.PutExtra("Url", AdsTable.rows[0].ContentUrl);
 intent.PutExtra("Type", AdsTable.rows[0].ContentType);
 intent.PutExtra("Id", AdsTable.rows[0].OID);
 StartActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Have you tested this with multiple devices? does it show any logs when it shows black screen? appreciate if you can share some code snippets with regard to your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

i solved like this maybe someone needs

```
wmParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager)getApplication().getSystemService(getApplication().WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wmParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
    wmParams.format = PixelFormat.RGBA_8888;
    wmParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
    wmParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER;
    wmParams.x = 0;
    wmParams.y = 0;
    wmParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    wmParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplication());
    mFloatLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.poplayout, null);
mWindowManager.addView(mFloatLayout, wmParams);
```